# Generating sequentially all combination of a finite set using lexicographic order and bitwise arithmetic

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, combinations, combinatorics

Consider all combination of length 3 of the following array of integer {1,2,3}.

I would like to traverse all combination of length 3 using the following algorithm from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications)

```
// find next k-combination    
bool next_combination(unsigned long& x) // assume x has form x'01^a10^b in binary
{
  unsigned long u = x & -x; // extract rightmost bit 1; u =  0'00^a10^b
  unsigned long v = u + x; // set last non-trailing bit 0, and clear to the right; v=x'10^a00^b
  if (v==0) // then overflow in v, or x==0
    return false; // signal that next k-combination cannot be represented
  x = v +(((v^x)/u)>>2); // v^x = 0'11^a10^b, (v^x)/u = 0'0^b1^{a+2}, and x ← x'100^b1^a
  return true; // successful completion
}
```

What should be my starting value for this algorithm for all combination of {1,2,3}?
When I get the output of the algorithm, how do I recover the combination?

I've try the following direct adaptation, but I'm new to bitwise arithmetic and I can't tell if this is correct.

```
// find next k-combination, Java    
int next_combination(int x)
{
  int u = x & -x; 
  int v = u + x; 
  if (v==0) 
    return v; 
  x = v +(((v^x)/u)>>2); 
  return x; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, say, running the code? N.B. the Wikipedia algorithm uses `x` as both an input and an output parameter. Java doesn't have those.

Comment: @MattBall When I run the code, it returns an integer. I don't know how to interpret it, nor how to translate it into a combination. I will edit my Java adaptation. It was a first attempt, just to analyse the wiki algorithm in debug mode. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I proceed per your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a class to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient, which is the type of problem that your problem falls under.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.  This method makes solving this type of problem quite trivial.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.  My paper talks about this.  I believe I am the first to discover and publish this technique, but I could be wrong.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.  I believe it might be faster than the link you have found.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to perform the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

It should not be hard to convert this class to Java.

Answer (score 3):

I found a class that exactly solve this problem. See the class CombinationGenerator here

https://bitbucket.org/rayortigas/everyhand-java/src/9e5f1d7bd9ca/src/Combinatorics.java

To recover a combination do

```
for(Long combination : combinationIterator(10,3))       
    toCombination(toPermutation(combination);
```

Thanks everybody for your input.